# Cordova Vue enable scrolling view when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, phonegap

I have problem with keyboard which overlaps input fields on my view:

[View without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxpUL.png)

[Keyboard overlaps input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUXqh.png)

When keyboard is showing, it shirnks my view but I solved this by using:

```xml
    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Now keyboard doesn't shrink view when it is about to show but still overlaps input fields. I want to enable scrolling view on Y axis only for this situation. Everything is happening inside `<div>` container tag which has:

```css
#app {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 85%;
  background-image: url("./assets/img/bg_menu_portrait.png");
}
```

I also tried to do something with:

```xml
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
```

but it makes things even worse. (when keyboard is about to show it shrinks view and also no scroll).

Any solution for this situation ? It seems that it is a common problem in Cordova/PhoneGap apps, I saw many solution on StackOverflow but none of them works for me...